# Chartjs doc examples are lightning fast but same code is slow when reproducing

Tags: javascript, performance, chart.js, rendering

Why are the example in the Chartjs documentation smooth and really fast, but when I try to reproduce it locally (same code, same browser (Firefox), <strike>same Chartjs version</strike>) it is considerably slower ? I tried using a Chrome-based browser as well, got the same issue.

Code from [Chartjs doughnut example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) :

```
  new Chart(document.getElementById("graphe").getContext('2d'), {"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["Red","Blue","Yellow"],"datasets":[{"label":"My First Dataset","data":[300,50,100],"backgroundColor":["rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(54, 162, 235)","rgb(255, 205, 86)"]}]}});
```

Here is how it looks like (it's not just the gif compression, it really is that slow):

[Fast (in documentation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODhYV.gif)

[Slow (locally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPJx7.gif)

Am I missing something here that'd explain such a speed difference ?

Answer (score 0):

I (wrongly) assumed that the documentation's version was the latest (i.e. 2.9.3) since the URL contains the version number which was "latest". However I tried all old releases and I seems like 2.8.0 "broke" something.

Chartjs 2.7.3 is fast, 2.8.0+ is not.